# How to edit locked properties in firefox about:config

Tags: firefox, firefox-10

I want to stop firefox from updating manually

```
 1. Tried to make the app.update.url as empty string, but it doesn't work. 
 2. Tried installing in some other folder rather than C:/ProgramFiles so that
    Automatically Install Updates option is not greyed out in Options>Advanced, but no success.
 3. Tried looking at prefs.js but the options which are locked in about:config don't 
    even appear in that file.
```

Tired of uninstalling and reinstalling firefox again and again. Does anyone know how to edit locked properties like **app.update.auto** and **app.update.enable** in **about:config**??

Comment: you can right-click on those properties select "Toggle" (if they're of a boolean value). this will change their values (from false to true or vice versa) and also have you tried changing the value of app.update.service.enabled to "false"?

Comment: since these properties are locked, the toggle option is greyed out. And I am not getting a way to unlock them

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem when I was trying to toggle App.update.enabled which was locked.
There are two places you need to search.
1. Firefox [Profile_folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder)

2. Firefox installation folder, like %PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox

To me, I found below string in one .cfg file, and after modify it, the lock flag gone.

```
"app.update.auto": {
  "value": false,
  "locked": true
},
```

I think it also applies to your problem.

Ref:
http://www.updatefreezer.org/index.php?id=22
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences
https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/13484/deploying-firefox-with-updates-disabled